# how to remove last few extra zeroes from timestamp column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to remove few extra zeroes from timestamp column

Eg: `04-NOV-17 09.22.47.000000000 PM`

i want something like this : `04-NOV-17 09.22.47.000`

only first three zeroes from milliseconds

i tried this `"TO_CHAR(column_name,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')"`  but it convert it into string but i need only in timestamp format.

Comment: `cast(column as timestamp(3))`?

Comment: its not working , extra zeroes still there

Comment: "I need only in timestamp format" - timestamp is a data type, with an internal reoresentation. You are *seeing* a string representation of the timestamp, whether you explicitly use `to_char` or not - your client just formats the string for you if not. A constraint on the datatype (like `timestamp(3)`) affects the stored precision, within that, trailing zeros effectively (implicitly) always exist, just as with fractions of numbers. If your client/application is expecting a timestamp then it's up to that to handle or display the value appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Solution from @jarlh is right.

For example `CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-06-19 08:54:41.928513' AS TIMESTAMP(3))` returns `2018-06-19 08:54:41.929`

However, your default output format for TIMESTAMP seems to be `DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF9 PM` thus on **output** it is always padded with zeros.

Try

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF PM';
```

then you should get only relevant digits for `FF` - three in your case.

From documentation [Datetime Format Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i34948)

> *FF [1..9]*
>
> Fractional seconds; no radix character is printed. Use the X format
>   element to add the radix character. Use the numbers 1 to 9 after FF to
>   specify the number of digits in the fractional second portion of the
>   datetime value returned. **If you do not specify a digit, then Oracle
>   Database uses the precision specified for the datetime data type or
>   the data type's default precision.** Valid in timestamp and interval
>   formats, but not in DATE formats.

Comment: i need to fetch few tables which are in oracle into hadoop and store in 'PARQET' format. so for that if there is any query or function in sql by which i can directly convert timestamp column  as i specified .

Comment: Yes, `CAST(... AS TIMESTAMP(3))` should do it, I don't understand your concern.

Comment: i have this timestamp format in oracle   04-NOV-17 09.22.47.000000000 , i want to remove last 6 zeroes , i tried that cast function but its not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work for me"? Please show us your code and results plus desired results.